# I'm taking this Oracle online java class and don't understand how origen point is (23,94) instead of 0,0

Tags: java

This example has three classes: Point, Rectangle and CreateObjectDemo. After running the program, origin point for rectTwo is 23,94 but according to the  constructor "public Rectangle(int w, int h)", I think it should be 0,0.

I am thinking this line "Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);" will call for the "public Rectangle(int w, int h)" constructor, so the origin point will be 0,0 because the first line of the constructor is  "origin = new Point(0, 0);"
But when I print the value of the origin, I get 23,94. Can someone help me to understand why the origin point is 23,94?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Point {
   public int x = 0;
   public int y = 0;

   public Point(int a, int b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
   }
```

}

```
public class Rectangle {
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public Point origin;

// four constructors
public Rectangle() {
    origin = new Point(0, 0);
}
public Rectangle(Point p) {
    origin = p;
}
public Rectangle(int w, int h) {
    origin = new Point(0, 0);

    width = w;
    height = h;
}
public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
    origin = p;
    width = w;
    height = h;
   }
}


public class CreateObjectDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declare and create a point object and two rectangle objects.
    Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
    Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
    Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);


    // display rectOne's width, height, and area
    System.out.println("Origen of rectone: " + rectOne.origin.x);
    System.out.println("Origen of rectone: " + rectOne.origin.y);        

    // set rectTwo's position
    rectTwo.origin = originOne;  

    // display rectTwo's position
    System.out.println("X Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.x);
    System.out.println("Y Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `rectTwo.origin = originOne` does?

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);
This line would call third constructor for rectangle , which means origin is (0,0) and w = 50, h = 100.

After that, you are calling this statement.
rectTwo.origin = originOne;  where originOne is (23,94)

This would essentially mean , you are overriding the origin for rectTwo object to be 23,94 instead of original (0,0).